# Отношения Laravel

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте.

Есть две модели InfoUser и User. InfoUser: id, user_id, balans. User: id, name....

Необходимо вывести на страницу поле balans, где InfoUser.user_id = User.id

Вот sql запрос:

```
SELECT InfoUser.balans FROM InfoUser INNER JOIN User ON User.id = InfoUser.user_id
```

Но я хочу это сделать через модель, но у меня чет не получается.

Вот как я сделал:

- В модель User прописал

  public function InfoUser()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\InfoUser','user_id');
      }
- В модель InfoUser:

  public function Info()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
- В контролере соответственно подключил обе модели(или можно только подключать модель User?) и написал вот такую строчку: `$InfoUser = InfoUser::find(1)->Info()->where('id','=',Auth::id());`
- Вот что выводит dd($InfoUser); 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вывести поле InfoUser.balans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InfoUser::find(1)->Info()->where('id','=',Auth::id())
```

Попробуйте изменить на такое

```
InfoUser::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->user->first()
```

User можно не подключать

в моделе InfoUser следует изменить на

```
public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }
```

и у вас связь 1 к 1, а не 1 ко многим
https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships#oo

Comment: То есть, если связь 1 к 1, следует изменить с hasMany на hasOne?

Comment: да, 1 юзер и информация только о 1 конкретном юзере

Comment: я вас ввел в заблуждение запрос будет выглядеть вот так :  `User::where('id', Auth::id())->userinfo->first()` вот так должно быть правильно

Comment: Угу)) чет ошибочка вышла:D

Comment: ошибка: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$InfoUser   У меня метод называется InfoUser в модели User, а в модели InfoUser метода User

Comment: в моделе юзер написанно hasOne?

Comment: Да, вот как в модели user public function InfoUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\InfoUser','user_id');
    }

Comment: `$info = User::where('id', Auth::id())->first()->InfoUser->balans` вот так должно работать)

Comment: угу, работает. А как достать всю инфу с таблице InfoUser по конкретному пользователю

Comment: `$info = User::where('id', Auth::id())->first()->InfoUser` переменная инфо должна содержать модель InfoUser

Comment: Благодарю за помощь